# Is it possible to emit valid YAML with anchors / references disabled using Ruby or Python?

Tags: python, ruby, yaml

Is it possible to disable creating anchors and references (and effectively list redundant data explicitly) either in `PyYAML` or Ruby's `Psych` engine?

Perhaps I missed something while searching the web, but it seems there are not many options available in `Psych` and I was not able to determine if `PyYAML` allows for that either.

The rationale is I have to serialize some data and pass it in a readable form to a not-really-technical co-worker for manual validation. Some data is redundant but I need it listed in a most explicit manner for readability (anchors and references are a nice concept for efficiency, but not for human-readability).

Ruby and Python are my tools of choice, but if there is some other reasonably simple way of 'unfolding' YAML documents, it might just do.

Comment: could you explain that with the expamples...? I don't see the connection of web, yaml, and anchors.

Comment: @majioa There's no 'web' involved - `anchor` in this context is an internal element of YAML syntax. See [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Advanced_components_of_YAML). It's apparently possible to disable them by duplicating objects (i.e. they are certainly used in case of object identity, but it seems I can't get a consistent pattern in case of object equality, e.g. for Ruby arrays), but it becomes a tedious task in case of deeply nested structures. I didn't try deep-copy libraries though.

Comment: I don't see the problem with storing/reading the array, they will have elements as you specify in a YAML file. Or you mean something else?

Comment: I see, you want to reuse a YAML code, right?

Comment: I just tried to load YAML file that is specified in example in the wiki. It correctly use anchors.

Comment: @majioa The point is I don't want them. Apparently defining your own dumper (while using `PyYAML`) and setting `ignore_aliases` to `True`, as described in Brett's answer, disables anchors and renders explicit (if redundant / duplicate) data, just as I need it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found this related ticket on the PyYAML website (http://pyyaml.org/ticket/91), it looks like anchors can be disabled by using a custom dumper along the lines of:

```
import yaml

class ExplicitDumper(yaml.SafeDumper):
    """
    A dumper that will never emit aliases.
    """

    def ignore_aliases(self, data):
        return True
```

So, for example, the following outputs can be achieved using the standard dumper and the new explicit dumper:

```
>>> yaml.dump([1L, 1L])
"[&id001 !!python/long '1', *id001]\n"

>>> yaml.dump([1L, 1L], Dumper=ExplicitDumper)
'[1, 1]\n'
```

You can customise further properties to ensure pretty-printing etc. in the `yaml.dump(...)` call.

Comment: For all I see it works very well. Thank you - +1 and accept from me ;)

Comment: For Ruby: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508364/how-to-emit-yaml-in-ruby-expanding-aliases/46104244#46104244